# Python - Ciclo for em alternativa ao ciclo while

Tags: python, for, while

Considerações genéricas:

- Estou de momento a programar em `python`;
- Tenho um código de nível  relativamente simples;
- O código contém um ciclo de instruções do tipo `while loop`;

Gostaria, de saber se há forma de correr o código abaixo especificado com uma instrução do tipo `for loop`, em vez de `while loop`:

```
 soma = 0 
 i = 20 
 while i >= 0: 
   soma += -i 
   i = i - 2 
   print('Soma =',soma)
 print('/'*30)
 soma = 0
 i = 20
```

**Estou a fazer assim:**

```
soma = 0
i = 20
for i in range(20, 0, -2):
  print('soma =', -i)
```

Contudo, não obtenho um output idêntico ao desejado

Agradeço desde já a vossa ajuda

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
soma = 0
i = 20
for i in range(20, 0, -2):
  soma += -i
  print('soma =', soma)
```

Answer (score 3):

Se você só quiser o resultado final:

```
print('soma = ', sum(range(-20,0,2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Bem, consegui resolver!
Fica aqui o código:

```
print('/'*30)
print('Ciclo FOR')
print('/'*30)

soma = 0
i = 20
for i in range(20, 0, -2):
  soma += -i
  print ('Soma =', soma)
```